# Display all parent records except those having 4 child records

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to display records from my sql from the parent table that have child records less than 4 or no child records, Need SQL query please.

More Clarification:

1. having no child records of a parent at all is also fine, all parent records should display
2. If the parent record has child records between 1 and 3, should display
3. if the parent record has exactly 4 child records, it shouldn't be displayed.

Schema (an employee can't have more than 4 donations)

client (client_id, email)

employee (employee_id, name)

donation (donation_id, employee_id, client_id)

SQL I've tried.

```
SELECT * FROM employee left join 
(SELECT donation_id, employee_id, client_id, count(employee_id) as count from donation      GROUP BY employee_id HAVING count <= 4) as d
ON employee.employee_id = d.employee_id
```

Comment: It would help to include your schema.  Also, [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: added schema, what I've tried, always end up with parent records that have a corresponding child records, I want parent records (all of them) to be displayed except the one's that have 4 child records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just join the tables, group by employee and filter the groups for those with less than 4 records:

```
SELECT   employee.*
FROM     employee LEFT JOIN donation USING (employee_id)
GROUP BY employee_id
HAVING   COUNT(*) < 4
```

Comment: chosen because of the simplest query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    a.employee_id, a.name
FROM      employee a
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT   employee_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
          FROM     donation
          GROUP BY employee_id
          ) b ON a.employee_id = b.employee_id
WHERE     b.cnt < 4 OR b.employee_id IS NULL
```

The `WHERE` clause basically includes only the parents who have less than 4 children (`b.cnt < 4`) OR who do not have any children at all (`b.employee_id IS NULL`).

Comment: It's not working, I still see employee records that have 4 child records (in donation table)

Comment: thanks, it's working now, I'd accept it as an answer, can you please describe this, specifically the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.* 
  FROM employee e 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT employee_id, count(parent_id) c 
    FROM donation
    GROUP BY employee_id
  ) s 
  ON s.employee_id = employee_id 
  WHERE s.c < 4 OR s.c IS NULL
```

and add this index

```
CREATE INDEX idx_employee_id ON donation (employee_id)
```